# iOS CoreBluetooth: startAdvertising() Error advertising static data

Tags: swift, core-bluetooth

I want to advertise static data. I'm using Swift 2.2.1 and CoreBluetooth on iOS. My app builds bluetooth *Services* and their corresponding *Characteristics*, then calls *startAdvertising()*, and the *peripheralManagerDidStartAdvertising90* callback returns this error:

```
peripheralManagerDidStartAdvertising encountered an error. // Mine
One or more parameters were invalid. // ...from Apple CoreBluetooth
nil  // ... return value from Apple CoreBluetooth callback
```

I'm relatively new to Swift and iOS development so my guess is that I'm doing something goofy, but so far I can't figure out what.

I'll attempt to distill things down for more experienced eyes.

```
- - - - - - pointutility.swift - - - - - - -
// This is a code excerpt and probably won't compile.

// UUID for the one peripheral service, declared outside the class:
var peripheralServiceUUID = CBUUID(string: "9BC1F0DC-F4CB-4159-BD38-7375CD0DD545")

// UUID for one characteristic of the service above, declared outside the class:
var nameCharacteristicUUID = CBUUID(string: "9BC1F0DC-F4CB-4159-BD38-7B74CD0CD546")

class PointUtility: NSObject, CBPeripheralManagerDelegate {

var peripheralManager:CBPeripheralManager?
var bluetoothServices:CBMutableService?
var nameCharacteristic:CBMutableCharacteristic?

override init() {
    super.init()
    peripheralManager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate:self, queue:nil)
    bluetoothServices = CBMutableService(type: peripheralServiceUUID, primary: true)
}

func configureUtilityForIdentity(identity:Point!) {
    var characteristicsArray:[CBCharacteristic] = []
    myIdentity = identity

      if (identity.name != nil) {
        nameCharacteristic =
            CBMutableCharacteristic(type: nameCharacteristicUUID,
                properties: (CBCharacteristicProperties.Read),
                value: myIdentity?.name?.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false),
                permissions: CBAttributePermissions.Readable)

        characteristicsArray.append(nameCharacteristic!)
      }

    // more characteristics built here and added to the characteristicsArray[]...
    // ... then all are added to the CBMutableService at the bottom...
    bluetoothServices?.characteristics = characteristicsArray as [CBCharacteristic]
}


func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(peripheral: CBPeripheralManager) {
    switch (peripheral.state) {
    case .PoweredOn:
        print("Current Bluetooth State:  PoweredOn")
        publishServices(bluetoothServices)
        break;
    case .PoweredOff:
        print("Current Bluetooth State:  PoweredOff")
        break;
    case .Resetting:
        print("Current Bluetooth State:  Resetting")
        break;
    case .Unauthorized:
        print("Current Bluetooth State:  Unauthorized")
    case .Unknown:
        print("Current Bluetooth State:  Unknown")
        break;
    case .Unsupported:
        /
        print("Current Bluetooth State:  Unsupported")
        break;
    }
}

func publishServices(newService:CBMutableService!) {
    peripheralManager?.addService(newService)
}

func peripheralManager(peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, didAddService service: CBService, error: NSError?) {

    if (error != nil) {
        print("PerformerUtility.publishServices() returned error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        print("Providing the reason for failure: \(error!.localizedFailureReason)")
    }
    else {
        peripheralManager?.startAdvertising([CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey : service.UUID])
    }
}

func peripheralManagerDidStartAdvertising(peripheral: CBPeripheralManager,
    error: NSError?) {
        if (error != nil) {
            print("peripheralManagerDidStartAdvertising encountered an error.")
            print(error!.localizedDescription)  // Error: One or more parameters were invalid
            print(error!.localizedFailureReason)  // Error: nil
        }
        print ("Debug: peripheralManagerDidStartAdvertising()")
}
}
- - - - - - pointutility.swift - - - - - - -
```

I really appreciate any assistance offered.

Best Regards,

Michael

Comment: Where do you call `configureUtilityForIdentity` ?

Comment: I created a simple, single-view app and configureUtilityForIdentity is being called in viewDidLoad()

Comment: But you create your peripheral manager in `init` so perhaps there is a race condition where the service is being advertised before you have called `configureUtility`?

Comment: Very thoughtful, thank you! I just moved the call to configureUtilityForIdentity to an IBAction that's called with a button depress. Still receiving the error message. :-(

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The value for the `CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey` in the dictionary passed to `startAdvertising` is an array of `CBUUID` objects, but you are only passing a single `CBUUID`.  Once I changed it to an array your code worked.

```
func peripheralManager(peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, didAddService service: CBService, error: NSError?) {

    if (error != nil) {
        print("PerformerUtility.publishServices() returned error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        print("Providing the reason for failure: \(error!.localizedFailureReason)")
    }
    else {
        peripheralManager?.startAdvertising([CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey : [service.UUID]])
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, so the append worked for you. I review my code again. It seemed broken when I first used it. Maybe they've fix it. I should work.

Comment: Here is the class I made to test your code.  I made some other changes, mostly using ! rather than ? but it should be much the same https://gist.github.com/paulw11/b2b33d7ff4c86818ac4d

Comment: Paulo11 can give me your email address? I just read your profile and thought it be good to get your details; I too graduated in CS last century in 1989, I sadly I have yet to have any apps on the store yet.

Comment: I overlooked the array. Adding it solved my problem, thank you! Actually, boundless gratitude to you both for tackling this problem and offering valuable insights. :-)

Comment: In a strange turn of events; I find myself improving my code having posted a solution; THANKYOU Paulw11.

Answer (score 1):

The error parameter in the method:

```
func peripheralManagerDidStartAdvertising(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, error: Error?)
```

Reports the error:

> Error Domain=CBErrorDomain Code=1 "One or more parameters were invalid." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=One or more parameters were invalid.}

Issue was needing to pass an **array** of UUIDs and also use the `CBUUID(string:)` type rather  than `UUID(uuidString:)`. Each issue reproduces the error independently.

```
struct BluetoothPeripheral {
    let localName: String
    let uuid: String

    func peripheralData() -> [String : Any] {
        return [
            CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey    : localName,
            CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey : [CBUUID(string: uuid)],
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a few minor points; I have an additional parameter.

```
peripheralManager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: nil)
```

I have this code in peripheralManagerDidUpdateState, right @ the top.

```
if (peripheral.state != .PoweredOn) {
    return;
}
```

And I call this within the same method, assuming it is powered on of course.

```
transferCharacteristic = CBMutableCharacteristic(type: cbtransfer, properties: .Notify, value: nil, permissions: .Readable)
transferService = CBMutableService(type: cbservice, primary: true)
transferService.characteristics = [transferCharacteristic]
```

Finally I do this:

```
peripheralManager!.addService(transferService)                    
peripheralManager!.startAdvertising([CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey :[cbservice]])
```

But note; I don't append the characteristics; I use the syntax you see here, appending doesn't work. For reasons I don't clearly understand Swift says its ok, but so it is syntactically good, but BLE doesn't like it.

```
func publishServices(newService:CBMutableService!) {
    peripheralManager?.addService(newService)
}
```

Review your code and make the changes; it should work.

Comment: [Added the additional parameter to `CBPeripheralManager`] [Changed `CBMutableCharacteristic` properties to accept `.Notify` <- makes better sense since I don't expect verification.] [Corrected `startAdvertising` to accept an **array** of `CBUUID` objects <- this was causing my error, yippee!] Question: How do you know BLE doesn't like appending of the characteristic? I see you're creating the `CBMutableCharacteristic` with _nil_ as the value parameter, which tells BLE the data is _dynamic_, rather than _static_. Maybe that has something to do with it?

Comment: I know cause I tried it and it didn't work; but maybe it was cause I passed it the wrong parameter, I double check.