# Testing CoreBluetooth

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

I am trying to get started with bluetooth on iOS, in order to make two neighbouring devices communicate using `CoreBluetooth`.

According to my understanding one device will have to play the role of peripheral and the other one the role of central.

I got started with writing a tiny app to play the role of peripheral.
Here is the relevant code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class ViewController: UIViewController,CBPeripheralManagerDelegate {
    let serviceOne_UUID = CBUUID(string:"FB694B90-F49E-4597-8306-171BBA78F846"),
    svcOneChrcOne_UUID = CBUUID(string:"EB6727C4-F184-497A-A656-76B0CDAC633A")
    var cbPerifMngr:CBPeripheralManager!, mutaSRVC:CBMutableService!,
    svcOneCharacOne:CBMutableCharacteristic!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        cbPerifMngr = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }


    // CBPeripheralManagerDelegate protocol implementation.

    func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager) {
        if peripheral.state == .poweredOn {
            mutaSRVC = CBMutableService(type: serviceOne_UUID, primary: true)
            svcOneCharacOne = CBMutableCharacteristic(type: svcOneChrcOne_UUID,
                                                      properties: .read, value: nil, permissions: .readable)
            mutaSRVC.characteristics = [svcOneCharacOne]
            cbPerifMngr?.add(mutaSRVC)
        }
    }


    func peripheralManager(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, didAdd service: CBService, error: Error?) {
        if error != nil {
            print("Error in \(#function) :\n\(error!)")
        } else {
            cbPerifMngr.startAdvertising([CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey:service.uuid])
        }
    }


    func peripheralManagerDidStartAdvertising(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, error: Error?) {
        if error != nil {
            print("Error in \(#function) :\n\(error!)")
        }
    }
}
```

My question at this point is: Is this enough to make another app playing the role of central communicate with it or not. And if it is not, what do I need to add to make a minimal peripheral app?

Comment: It isn't.  You need to create an instance of `CBMutablePeripheral`, add a service and at least one characteristic.  The string in the advertisement dictionary isn't just an arbitrary value such as `prime` - It needs to be `CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey` with an array service uuids and optionally `CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey` - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheralmanager/1393252-startadvertising.

Comment: Following you comments, I am trying to make it work. I must say I see a lot of questions in the process. I also found this other post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35858183/ios-corebluetooth-startadvertising-error-advertising-static-data. It gives me some hints, but there are also a few unclear points. Like where does those values (peripheralServiceUUID,nameCharacteristicUUID) come from? And what is this parameter of type POINT? In configureUtilityForIdentity?

Comment: You can just make up any UUIDs you like. `Point` is some object that the creator of that question created

Comment: OK. I found that I can use the command line uuidgen to create an arbitrary UUID and use it. But it seems I still have a lot to figure out in order to create a minimum app playing the role of a peripheral. Setting up services, characteristics ..... seems like a bit of a headache to me at this point. Or maybe I have not found the right tutorial.

Comment: This is basically all you need to create and advertise a service - https://gist.github.com/paulw11/971d97b0d07ac6ea0888bebaac1390b9

Comment: I have updated the post to reflect the new state of my tiny app. Strongly influenced I have to admit by your comment and what I read after seeing it. The question basically stays the same, but the starting point is rather different. Therefore the answer may vary quite a bit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185643/discussion-between-michel-and-paulw11).